# Error when using the OpenRouteService API with QGIS

Tags: qgis, api

I had been using the OpenRouteService API to create isochrones in QGIS with no problem, but now I'm getting an error as follow. I've verified the token quota has not been exceeded. I'm getting the error even with the exact same parameters I'd been using before. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Edit: Have tried spacing the requests 5 / 30 / 60 seconds, also deleting current token and creating and using a new one, getting the same error.

> OverQueryLimit: Retrying...
> OverQueryLimit: Retrying...
> OverQueryLimit: Retrying...
> OverQueryLimit: Retrying...
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ORStools\common\client.py", line 157, in request
> response, content = self.nam.request(self.url,
> File "C:\Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ORStools\common\networkaccessmanager.py", line 263, in request
> raise self.http_call_result.exception
> ORStools.common.networkaccessmanager.RequestsException: Network error #429: Error transferring https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/isochrones/foot-walking? - server replied: Too Many Requests
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ORStools\common\client.py", line 167, in request
> self._check_status()
> File "C:\Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ORStools\common\client.py", line 217, in _check_status
> raise exceptions.OverQueryLimit(
> ORStools.utils.exceptions.OverQueryLimit: 429 ({
> "error": "Rate limit exceeded"
> })
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ORStools\common\client.py", line 157, in request
> response, content = self.nam.request(self.url,
> File "C:\Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ORStools\common\networkaccessmanager.py", line 263, in request
> raise self.http_call_result.exception
> ORStools.common.networkaccessmanager.RequestsException: Network error #429: Error transferring https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/isochrones/foot-walking? - server replied: Too Many Requests
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ORStools\common\client.py", line 167, in request
> self._check_status()
> File "C:\Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ORStools\common\client.py", line 217, in _check_status
> raise exceptions.OverQueryLimit(
> ORStools.utils.exceptions.OverQueryLimit: 429 ({
> "error": "Rate limit exceeded"
> })
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ORStools\common\client.py", line 157, in request
> response, content = self.nam.request(self.url,
> File "C:\Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ORStools\common\networkaccessmanager.py", line 263, in request
> raise self.http_call_result.exception
> ORStools.common.networkaccessmanager.RequestsException: Network error #429: Error transferring https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/isochrones/foot-walking? - server replied: Too Many Requests
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ORStools\common\client.py", line 167, in request
> self._check_status()
> File "C:\Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ORStools\common\client.py", line 217, in _check_status
> raise exceptions.OverQueryLimit(
> ORStools.utils.exceptions.OverQueryLimit: 429 ({
> "error": "Rate limit exceeded"
> })
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ORStools\common\client.py", line 157, in request
> response, content = self.nam.request(self.url,
> File "C:\Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ORStools\common\networkaccessmanager.py", line 263, in request
> raise self.http_call_result.exception
> ORStools.common.networkaccessmanager.RequestsException: Network error #429: Error transferring https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/isochrones/foot-walking? - server replied: Too Many Requests
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ORStools\common\client.py", line 167, in request
> self._check_status()
> File "C:\Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ORStools\common\client.py", line 217, in _check_status
> raise exceptions.OverQueryLimit(
> ORStools.utils.exceptions.OverQueryLimit: 429 ({
> "error": "Rate limit exceeded"
> })
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ORStools\proc\isochrones_layer_proc.py", line 155, in processAlgorithm
> response = ors_client.request('/v2/isochrones/' + profile, {}, post_json=params)
> File "C:\Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ORStools\common\client.py", line 176, in request
> return self.request(url, params, first_request_time, retry_counter + 1, post_json)
> File "C:\Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ORStools\common\client.py", line 176, in request
> return self.request(url, params, first_request_time, retry_counter + 1, post_json)
> File "C:\Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ORStools\common\client.py", line 176, in request
> return self.request(url, params, first_request_time, retry_counter + 1, post_json)
> [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
> File "C:\Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ORStools\common\client.py", line 121, in request
> raise exceptions.Timeout()
> ORStools.utils.exceptions.Timeout
>
> Execution failed after 15.64 seconds

Screenshot from ORS dev dashboard:
[image]

Comment: How did you "verify" that you haven't exceeded the token quota? How hard are you hitting this API (e.g in requests per minute)?

Comment: I checked on the ORS dev dashboard (adding screenshot to post). I've tried spacing the requests 5, 30 and 60 seconds, with the same result.

Comment: I found from my experience you often have to wait for a day when you get error messages like this and then it starts working again. Also I know for large datasets they say it is better to run ORS in docker rather than use the API but I could not figure this out when I tried.